# GetWindowRect returns NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, function, pinvoke, native

I'm trying to get size and position of a certain window attached to javaw.exe process.

Sadly, GetWindowRect throws an error: "NullReferenceException" - and I've checked, none of it's arguments == null.

Here's the piece of code

Invoking sample:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr handle, out WindowRect rect);
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private class WindowRect
    {
        public int Left;
        public int Top;
        public int Right;
        public int Bottom;
    }
```

Running static function to attach process:

`NB.Attach( Process.GetProcessesByName("javaw")[0] );`

Usage sample:

```
    public static void Attach( Process process )
    {
        FocusProcess = process;
        FocusWindow = FindWindow(null, process.MainWindowTitle);
    }

    public static int[] GetWindowPosition()
    {
        WindowRect rect = new WindowRect();

        Console.WriteLine(FocusProcess == null);
        Console.WriteLine(FocusProcess.MainWindowHandle == null);
        Console.WriteLine(rect==null);
        GetWindowRect(FocusProcess.MainWindowHandle, out rect);
        if ( rect.Top != 0 )
        {
            return new int[] { rect.Left, rect.Top };
        }
        return new int[] { 0, 0 };
    }
```

Thanks in advance, I'm totally inexperienced if it comes to usage of native functions.

Comment: Are you sure this is the full code? There's certainly something missing here as `NullReferenceException` is a .Net exception and `GetWindowRect` won't throw that.

Comment: It is the full code and error points to me trying to use GetWindowRect();

Comment: Well it can't be as `FocusProcess` is not defined here. Can you post the full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: I'll post the other code aswell too then

Comment: Rect is a structure not a class and all its members are of type long not int. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162897(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I'm surprised that works without being `private struct WindowRect` or being  `[Out] rect`.

Comment: @Suraj No, long is 64 bits in C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared the struct as a C# class. That's a reference type already. So when you pass it as an out param you now have a double pointer. Either

- Change from class to struct,
- or pass the class by value.

Comment: Works flawlessly - you have no idea how many combinations I've tried.. struct, class, out, ref - but at all times it didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Winner winner chicken dinner